# How to fetch value according to the proper order using PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need one help.I need to fetch value according to the one certain order using PHP and Mysql.I am explaining my table below.

> db_subcategory:

```
id      cat_id        name                order

1       10            happy hour             1

2       10            wine                   3

3       10            water                  2

4       11            pizza                  1

5       10            beer                   2
```

Here i need `query` in Mysql to fetch all name whose `cat_id=10` according to the order.It should come as per order`1,2,3...` if for order value `2` there are two set of name,in this case the name will come alphabetically.Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name
FROM db_subcategory
WHERE cat_id = 10
ORDER BY `order`, name
```

**EDIT**: It might also needed to add backticks for *order* because it is a keyword.

[**Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8cd8a).

Answer (score 0):

`Order by` with two columns will do.

```
select * from db_subcategory where cat_id = 10 order by order, name
```